# Python ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to make my code Python code run, however, I am running into import errors (shown below). I have looked up some possible solutions and no luck after trying them out.

My directory level is fairly simple.

```
Python
    pkgA
        __init__.py
        verify.py
        console.py
```

I used to be able to run `console.py` and was working fine, however, I've been trying to clean up the imports and make the python package installable.

When I run `console.py` it throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Repositories/Python/pkgA/console.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..pkgA import verify
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

My `console.py` has this import `from ..supv import verify`

I've tried manipulating the paths to try to make it work, but it hasn't been successful.

Comment: Why not just `from . import verify`? There is no package above `pkgA` in your structure so you cannot go further than that without Python complaining. Besides, if you're making the package installable, it will be added to the `site-packages` and then you don't need a relative import for the `pkgA` at all.

Comment: @zwer Thanks! however, when I tried that I'm getting another error. `from . import verify; ImportError: cannot import name 'verify'` I'm still reading up on how to make the package installable but for now, to test my code, I will need it to compile.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of something I found an answer for on Stackoverflow.. `if __name__ == '__main__':
    if __package__ is None:
        import os, sys
        from os import path
        sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
        sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))`

Comment: @JGFMK So this code would be added to which module `console.py`?

Comment: Exactly. That worked for me.

Comment: @JGFMK Doesnt work for me :(